# Add django variable to <select> tag

Tags: python, django

I have variable **CHOICES** and ListView.

```
CHOICES = [
        ('ALL', 'ALL'),
        ('IT', 'IT'),
        ('FINANCE', 'FINANCE'),
        ('OTHER', 'OTHER'),
]

class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancy_list/vacancy_list.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    page_kwarg = 'vacancy'
    context_object_name = 'vacancies'
    queryset = Vacancy.objects.order_by('-published_date')
```

How can I add CHOICES to the html tag  ?

I want to replace `<option>IT</option>`  to something like **for department in CHOICES**

**full code**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <select name="q2" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <option>{{ user.department }}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option>ALL</option>
        {% endif %}
             <option>IT</option>
             <option>Finance</option>
             <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I tried

```
{% for department in CHOICES %}
    <option value={{ department.0 }}>{{ department.1 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

but CHOICES is empty

Comment: Please don't put this in the template, but in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you use a [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) or `TypedChoiceField` in a Django form, and to a greater or lesser extent the `<select>` structure is automagical when you render the form in your template.

But for edge cases you can indeed pass it to your template as Tushortz shows in his answer.

Comment: I tried Tushortz code, but  CHOICES is empty. How can I add CHOICES?

Comment: Add it to the context passed to the template. `return render( ...)` with `"CHOICES":CHOICES` in the context. Or override the `get_context` method to add CHOICES if you use class-based views.

Answer (score 1):

you need something like

```
{% for department in CHOICES %}
  <option value={{ department.0 }}>{{ department.1 }}</option>
(% endfor %}
```

make sure `CHOICES` is passed as a context from your view

Comment: I tried this code, but but CHOICES is empty. How can I add CHOICES?

Comment: CHOICES needs to be placed in your views or you can import it from your moels.py into your views.py

Answer (score 0):

Correct way -

```
{% for department in CHOICES %}
  <option value="{{department[0]}}">{{ department[1] }}</option>
(% endfor %}
```